# Calculating min of other fields using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator

How can I calculate the min of other fields?

For example, I have 3 fields: a, b and c.

I want to have a field that shows me the minimum value of the 3 field. Finally, I want to know the minimum value is of a or b or c.

Answer (score 4):

Using Python in the Field Calculator, here's how you would determine the minimum value across 3 fields.

```
min([!field1!, !field2!, !field3!])
```

Then to identify which of the 3 fields contains the minimum value, you can just do a series of *Select By Attributes* queries

"field1" = "minfield" (or whatever you call your new minimum value field)

then calculate a new text field equal to whichever field name you use in your query.

Answer (score 1):

Here are code snippets for ArcMap 10.0

```
arcpy.Statistics_analysis("futrds", "C:/output/output.gdb/stats", [["a", "MIN"],["b", "MIN"],["c", "MIN"]])
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(C:/output/output.gdb/stats")
for row in rows:
    min_values = [row.min_a, row.min_b, row.min_c].sort()
    min_val = min_values[0]
```